# What is wrong with this Java code? Why can't I put in HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

```
class{
    public HashMap<String, String> eachperson;  

    apple(){
        this.eachperson.put("thekey","thevalue");
    }
}
```

(Please excuse the public/privates in front of the class and function. I just want to know if I'm putting the hash map correctly. )

For the true code, please see below:

```
class ParsedDataSet{
    public HashMap<String, String> eachperson;      
    public List<HashMap<String,String>> peoplelist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
}

class ListprofileHandler extends DefaultHandler{
    private boolean in_results = true;
    private boolean in_item = false;
    private boolean in_first_name = false;
    private boolean in_last_name = false;
    private boolean in_picture_url = false;
    private boolean in_enditem_dummy = false;
    private ParsedDataSet dset = new ParsedDataSet();
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        if(localName.equals("results")){
            this.in_results = true;
        }else if(localName.equals("item")){
            this.in_item = true;
        }else if(localName.equals("first_name")){
            this.in_first_name = true;
        }else if(localName.equals("last_name")){
            this.in_last_name = true;
        }else if(localName.equals("picture_url")){
            this.in_picture_url = true;
        }else if(localName.equals("enditem_dummy")){
            this.in_enditem_dummy = true;
        }
    }
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)throws SAXException {
        if(localName.equals("results")){
            this.in_results = false;
        }else if(localName.equals("item")){
            this.in_item = false;
        }else if(localName.equals("first_name")){
            this.in_first_name = false;
        }else if(localName.equals("last_name")){
            this.in_last_name = false;
        }else if(localName.equals("picture_url")){
            this.in_picture_url = false;
        }else if(localName.equals("enditem_dummy")){
            this.in_enditem_dummy = false;
        }
    }           
    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        if(this.in_first_name){
            dset.eachperson.put("first_name", new String(ch, start, length));
        }
        if(this.in_enditem_dummy){
            dset.peoplelist.add(dset.eachperson);
            dset.eachperson = new HashMap<String,String>();  //Reached a new item. So reset the temporary hashmap.
        }

    }       

    public ParsedDataSet getParsedListData(){
        return this.dset;
    }   
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Don't just say "Why cant I?"

Comment: I don't know the error, because I'm doing Android, and it pops up this weird Edit Source thing.

Comment: Create a new project in eclipse or whatever and see what does compiler says about that, you might get additional errors but look  for the one describing something about your hashmap, maybe it has to do with run time environment(most probably).

Comment: Tag this as an "Android" question. And check your Logcat window in Eclipse (available in the "DDMS" perspective - http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html)

Comment: BTW, you don't need the "this" in front of eachperson.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The specific error that you are receiving would be helpful.  However, I don't see where you are initializing your `HashMap` for the first add.  You declare it up top with no assignment, and then you attempt to use it in the `if(this.in_first_name)` case without assigning it.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared a variable called 'eachperson' that is of type HashMap but you never initialized. Also, it is usually best practice to use the Map interface to 'use' the map in case you need to change the map implementation.

Replace the eachperson declaration that the HashMap issue should be solved.

```
public HashMap<String,String> eachperson = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

You did have some code to 'reset' the HashMap after it gets the 'characters' element. Note that characters will occur after startElement so your map was never initialized before it was used the first time. You might also want to use 'clear' instead of recreating the map.

```
dset.eachperson.clear();
```

That will clear your map but does not require creating a new instance.